# FontButton Font change not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, gtk

I'm using the following code to obtain the selected font from a FontButton. But the fontName doesn't change even if I choose a different font... the size works though.

```
protected void OnFontbutton2FontSet (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string sfont = fontbutton2.FontName; 

        string fontName = sfont.Substring(0,sfont.LastIndexOf(' '));

        int fontSize = int.Parse(sfont.Substring(sfont.LastIndexOf(' ')+1).Trim());// I know, looks a bit ugly 
        cfont = new Font(fontName ,fontSize, FontStyle.Regular,System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            selectedfont=new Font(fontName ,fontSize, FontStyle.Regular,System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog (this, DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent, MessageType.Info, ButtonsType.Close, fontName);
        int result = md.Run ();
        MessageDialog md2 = new MessageDialog (this, DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent, MessageType.Info, ButtonsType.Close, selectedfont.Name);
        int result2 = md2.Run ();
        if (wwork.IsBusy == false) {
            wwork.RunWorkerAsync ();
        } else {
            bgdirty = true; 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

But the newly created font `cfont` object stays as the default font, only the font size changes... font name does not change.

What am I doing wrong? Please advice.

UPDATE:
Console Output with Font Variable(font) Name Printed after setting

```
System.Drawing.Font myfont = new Font ("Tahoma", 50, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

---

```
 Loaded assembly: /Users/me/Desktop/testproject/fonttest/fonttest/bin/Debug/fonttest.exe
    Loaded assembly: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll [External]
    Loaded assembly: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1/lib/mono/gac/glib-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/glib-sharp.dll [External]
    Loaded assembly: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1/lib/mono/gac/atk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/atk-sharp.dll [External]
    Loaded assembly: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll [External]
    Loaded assembly: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1/lib/mono/gac/gdk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gdk-sharp.dll [External]
    Loaded assembly: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll [External]
    Loaded assembly: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll [External]
    Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
    Lucida Grande
```

Comment: Have you tried debug messages to show what the variables are set to at each stage of execution? Please post those. And also, I agree with the answer about avoiding threading.

Comment: @oldtechaa Thanks for your help.. Yeah.. i have checked using `MessageDialog`  please see the code..It does not work even if i do like this manually `System.Drawing.Font cfont=new Font("Tahoma","10", FontStyle.Regular,System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);`

Comment: @oldtechaa I had removed the threading .. added a button and used it to display the current font selection.. the font name does not change..

Comment: I mean debug every single variable (including `sfont`, etc.); preferably, as it gets set. This should be possible with terminal output, but if you can't easily do that, message dialogs are fine. Could you post the outputs? What's the difference between `cfont` and `selectedfont`?

Comment: @oldtechaa I have created a simple project with a single button to set the font manually and printed out he set font name in console.. Its the default font.I have attached the whole project here https://www.sendspace.com/file/ozt7nv .Can you please check.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a C# environment set up. Do you mind running your simple project and posting the output of every variable as it runs?

Comment: @oldtechaa Sorry for the late reply.. please see my update..

Comment: Sorry to keep posting this, but _please_ post an example with debug output of _every single variable_ to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to modify the font name using `sfont.Substring()`. Many fonts will have spaces in their names.

And in fact, while you can use the individual font attributes, you should be getting a PangoFontDescriptor and using that instead, via the `font-desc` property. You can then copy that descriptor, modify it, and then use it in drawing operations.

Your threading stuff looks suspicious. You can't do anything with GTK+ from a worker thread. If you want to redraw your widget, use `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` or one of the related functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. fontName is returning proper value.If this was the issue Fonts with a single word should work properly.. i suppose.Even if `fontName`  returns the correct string and i create a new font from it like this ` cfont=new Font(fontName ,fontSize, FontStyle.Regular,System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);`   The value of `cfont` stays the same.

Comment: Are you sure `fontName` isn't returning something like `My Font Regular` or `My Font 10`?

Comment: Yeah... I printed it out using a `MessageDialog`.This code is written specifically to separate `fontname` and `fontsize`  int `fontSize=int.Parse(sfont.Substring(sfont.LastIndexOf(' ')+1).Trim());` I have updated the code..Please check..

Comment: The newly created font object `cfont` have the new size ..but the font name stays as the old default font.

Comment: I have created a simple project with a single button to set the font manually and printed out he set font name in console.. Its the default font.I have attached the whole project here https://www.sendspace.com/file/ozt7nv .Can you please check

Answer (score 0):

Use `Font` class from `System.Drawing` Namespace 
Instead of `string sfont = fontbutton2.FontName;` use  `string sfont = fontbutton2.Font.Name;`

EDIT 1, Try it this way:

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Tahoma");
System.Drawing.Font cfont = new Font(
   fontFamily,
   10, FontStyle.Regular,System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: The class of `cfont` is `System.Drawing.Font`  and this `System.Drawing.Font cfont=new Font("Tahoma","10", FontStyle.Regular,System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);` does not work.